# Rearrange convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, conjectures

It was long time ago I studied analyze and I do have forgot a lot, but isn't it so that any convergent series
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$$
can be rearranged to an absolut convergent series
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} b_{ij}\right|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$ 
where the $b_{ij}$-s is a rearrangement of the $a_k$-s?

Comment: What did you mean by $\{a_i\}_i=\{b_{ij}\}_{i,j}$?

Comment: Also, did you mean to say that $\sum_i \sum_j |b_{ij}|<\infty$?

Comment: You might be remembering the following result: If $\sum a_n$ converges, there exists some increasing $(n(k))$ such that $A_k=\sum\limits_{n=n(k)}^{n(k+1)-1}a_n$ defines an absolutely convergent series $\sum A_n$, that is, such that $\sum|A_n|$ converges. Proof: Choose $n(k)$ recursively such that $n(k+1)>n(k)$ and $\left|\sum\limits_{n=n(k+1)}^{\infty}a_n\right|\leqslant\frac1{k^2}$. End of the proof.

Comment: @Did: is $\sum A_n=\sum a_n$?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Better if you write an expanded version of this as an answer.